# Does the grpc server use one new goroutine to process one method call?

Tags: go, grpc

How does golang grpc implementation handle the server concurrency?

One goroutine per method call? Or sort of goroutine pool?

Does it depend on the concurrency model of net/http2?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One goroutine per method call. There's current no goroutine pool for service handlers.

It doesn't depend on net/http2 concurrency model.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/concurrency.md#servers

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/091a800143380a06a4721749da705ccbf4ae5e7a/server.go#L678

Comment: You are legend. Thanks.